# Unable to send message to different queue parallely using 1 channel from java mq client via mqipt

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I am sending message from Java MQ client application to IBM MQ via Apache and mqipt on single Server connection channel. It works fine when I send or receive message from any queue.

But when i start sending message to multiple queue parallelly either using single connection and multiple session or multiple connection per queue, it starts for some time and then fails with error
:

**JMS attempted to close an IBM MQ destination, but encountered an error. The destination might already be closed, or another thread may be performing an MQGET while close() is called.**

Complete Stack trace

```
[ibmmq-test][2021-05-04 22:26:50][Thread-3][ERROR][MQPushAndPullTestForDBThreadQueue:267] - Error in message sending JMSException JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'QM.SGU00419' with connection mode '1' and host name 'localhost(1414)'.
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'QM.SGU00419' with connection mode '1' and host name 'localhost(1414)'.
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:595) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:215) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSession.connect(WMQSession.java:460) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSession.<init>(WMQSession.java:352) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.createSession(WMQConnection.java:961) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsConnectionImpl.createSession(JmsConnectionImpl.java:869) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsQueueConnectionImpl.createQueueSession(JmsQueueConnectionImpl.java:112) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnection.createQueueSession(MQQueueConnection.java:131) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.hcl.apacil.config.MQPushAndPullTestForDBThreadQueue$TestQueueSender.run(MQPushAndPullTestForDBThreadQueue.java:215) [classes/:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_181]
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2009' ('MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN').
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:203) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    ... 8 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2009;AMQ9204: Connection to host 'localhost(1414)' rejected. [1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2009],3=localhost(1414),5=RemoteSession.receiveAsyncTsh]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP$Connector.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:13588) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP$Connector.access$100(RemoteFAP.java:13125) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1430) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1389) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.InterceptedJmqiImpl.jmqiConnect(InterceptedJmqiImpl.java:377) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.ESEJMQI.jmqiConnect(ESEJMQI.java:562) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSession.connect(WMQSession.java:409) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    ... 7 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2009
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteSession.receiveAsyncTsh(RemoteSession.java:612) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteSession.receiveTSH(RemoteSession.java:805) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteSession.receiveMQIFlow(RemoteSession.java:1459) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP$Connector.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:13410) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP$Connector.access$100(RemoteFAP.java:13125) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1430) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1389) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.InterceptedJmqiImpl.jmqiConnect(InterceptedJmqiImpl.java:377) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.ESEJMQI.jmqiConnect(ESEJMQI.java:562) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSession.connect(WMQSession.java:409) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    ... 7 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2009
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.asyncConnectionBroken(RemoteConnection.java:3837) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteRcvThread.run(RemoteRcvThread.java:587) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.runTask(WorkQueueItem.java:319) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.SimpleWorkQueueItem.runItem(SimpleWorkQueueItem.java:99) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.run(WorkQueueItem.java:343) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueManager.runWorkQueueItem(WorkQueueManager.java:312) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.workqueue.WorkQueueManagerImplementation$ThreadPoolWorker.run(WorkQueueManagerImplementation.java:1227) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2009;AMQ9208: Error on receive from host 'localhost/127.0.0.1:1414 (localhost)'. [1=-1,2=ffffffff,3=localhost/127.0.0.1:1414 (localhost),4=TCP]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteRcvThread.receiveBuffer(RemoteRcvThread.java:796) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteRcvThread.receiveOneTSH(RemoteRcvThread.java:739) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteRcvThread.run(RemoteRcvThread.java:156) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.runTask(WorkQueueItem.java:319) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.SimpleWorkQueueItem.runItem(SimpleWorkQueueItem.java:99) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.run(WorkQueueItem.java:343) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueManager.runWorkQueueItem(WorkQueueManager.java:312) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.workqueue.WorkQueueManagerImplementation$ThreadPoolWorker.run(WorkQueueManagerImplementation.java:1227) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ2000: Failed to close queue 'HCLGIS.EBRIDGE.CH.OUT'.
JMS attempted to close an IBM MQ destination, but encountered an error. The destination might already be closed, or another thread may be performing an MQGET while close() is called.
Use the linked exception to determine the cause of this error. You may be able to perform the close() later.
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:595)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:215)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer.checkJmqiCallSuccess(WMQMessageProducer.java:1293)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer.access$400(WMQMessageProducer.java:76)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer$SpiIdentifiedProducerShadow.close(WMQMessageProducer.java:764)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer.close(WMQMessageProducer.java:1338)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageProducerImpl.close(JmsMessageProducerImpl.java:243)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.close(JmsSessionImpl.java:571)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsConnectionImpl.close(JmsConnectionImpl.java:511)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnection.close(MQConnection.java:90)
    at com.hcl.apacil.config.MQPushAndPullTestForDBThreadQueue$TestQueueSender.run(MQPushAndPullTestForDBThreadQueue.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[ibmmq-test][2021-05-04 22:26:50][Thread-4][INFO ][MQPushAndPullTestForDBThreadQueue:263] - Connection Closed 2:
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2009' ('MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN').
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:203)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2009;AMQ9206: Error sending data to host 'localhost/127.0.0.1:1414 (localhost)'. [1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2009],3=localhost/127.0.0.1:1414 (localhost),4=TCP,5=RemoteTCPConnection.send(byte [ ],int,int,int,int)]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.send(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1675)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.wrapSend(RemoteConnection.java:2976)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.sendTSH(RemoteConnection.java:2742)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteSession.sendTSH(RemoteSession.java:775)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteSession.sendTSH(RemoteSession.java:691)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.MQCLOSE(RemoteFAP.java:6764)
    at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.InterceptedJmqiImpl.MQCLOSE(InterceptedJmqiImpl.java:599)
    at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.ESEJMQI.MQCLOSE(ESEJMQI.java:315)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer$SpiIdentifiedProducerShadow.close(WMQMessageProducer.java:734)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2009
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.asyncConnectionBroken(RemoteConnection.java:3837)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteRcvThread.run(RemoteRcvThread.java:587)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.runTask(WorkQueueItem.java:319)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.SimpleWorkQueueItem.runItem(SimpleWorkQueueItem.java:99)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.run(WorkQueueItem.java:343)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueManager.runWorkQueueItem(WorkQueueManager.java:312)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.workqueue.WorkQueueManagerImplementation$ThreadPoolWorker.run(WorkQueueManagerImplementation.java:1227)
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2009;AMQ9208: Error on receive from host 'localhost/127.0.0.1:1414 (localhost)'. [1=-1,2=ffffffff,3=localhost/127.0.0.1:1414 (localhost),4=TCP]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteRcvThread.receiveBuffer(RemoteRcvThread.java:796)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteRcvThread.receiveOneTSH(RemoteRcvThread.java:739)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteRcvThread.run(RemoteRcvThread.java:156)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: What did the MQIPT log show? What is the HBINT of your SVRCONN channel?  Can you enable reconnect to work around it?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to share a connection handle (and possibly closing and/or disconnecting while other threads are still running).  i.e. 1 connection among multiple putters.  You can use the same channel name but each putter (thread) needs to have its _**own**_ connection to the queue manager.

Comment: @JoshMc@Roger MQIPT log show connection reset with following response         10:57:18.843    30   1414-2s         IPTException: closeId=ERROR, closeMsg=Connection reset, rc=60010
10:57:18.843    30   1414-2s         ...caused by:
10:57:18.843    30   1414-2s         java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
10:57:18.843    30   1414-2s                     HBINT is 300. tried with reconnect as well not working also tried with multiple connection for each putter on QM

Comment: Try setting your HBINT to 15 seconds.

Comment: `JMSWMQ2000: Failed to close queue 'HCLGIS.EBRIDGE.CH.OUT'.
JMS attempted to close an IBM MQ destination, but encountered an error. The destination might already be closed, or another thread may be performing an MQGET while close() is called.
Use the linked exception to determine the cause of this error. You may be able to perform the close() later.`

Comment: Do you close between get and put operations?   If so why?